# How to fix error during groovy installation

Tags: groovy

Starting groovy via the console gives me following error related to java:

> Start after installing groovy. and writting groovysh in command line.
>
> C:\Users\amiii>groovysh java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)
>           at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.rootLoader(GroovyStarter.java:110)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.main(GroovyStarter.java:128)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Unable to load class
>   org.apache.groovy.jaxb.extensions.JaxbExtensions due to missing
>   dependency javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v5.Java5.configureClassNode(Java5.java:414)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.lazyClassInit(ClassNode.java:281)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.getMethods(ClassNode.java:406)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.macro.transform.MacroMethodsCache.scanExtClasses(MacroMethodsCache.java:88)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.macro.transform.MacroMethodsCache.access$000(MacroMethodsCache.java:45)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.macro.transform.MacroMethodsCache$2.onModule(MacroMethodsCache.java:69)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.m12n.ExtensionModuleScanner.scanExtensionModuleFromProperties(ExtensionModuleScanner.java:87)

Comment: Please try to conform to [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please improve your question.

Comment: Provide the versions of java and groovy you are using, and your operating system.